# Kivy: Kivy launcher fall down

Tags: python, kivy

I have simple code for kivy, on W10 runs without problem. It falls down during loading in kivy launcher. Problem is without message.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class View(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.text = "No text"
        but = Button(text = "Press",on_press = self.show)
        self.add_widget(but)
        self.lbl = Label()
        self.add_widget(self.lbl)

    def show(self,obj):
        self.lbl.text = self.text
        pass



class MyPaintApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return View()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not run because you call `super` wrong.
As kivy launcher uses python 2, you need to pass your class (View) and the instance (self) to super.

You need to edit your class like this:

```
class View(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(View,self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but the problem isn't the OS. That code is not compatible with Python 2. The possibility of using super without arguments was introduced in Python 3: [PEP--3135  New Super()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/)

Comment: @FJSevilla thank you. I ran it with python 2. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank You! Code is loading without problem.

Answer (score -1):

in every failure in kivy launcher, there is a '.kivy/log' directory inside the project directory that has a full log. you could find all the problem there.